# Chart without Axis Lines

Tags: c#, charts

I'm trying to create chart programmatically. Here is code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xvals = new[]
            {
                new DateTime(2012, 4, 4), 
                new DateTime(2012, 4, 5), 
                new DateTime(2012, 4, 6), 
                new DateTime(2012, 4, 7)
            };
        var yvals = new[] { 1, 3, 7, 12 };

        // create the chart
        var chart = new Chart();
        chart.Width = 600;
        chart.Height = 350;

        var chartArea = new ChartArea();
        chartArea.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
        chartArea.AxisY.IsMarginVisible = false;
        chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd";
        chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        chartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
        chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

        var series = new Series();
        series.Name = "Series1";
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;            
        chart.Series.Add(series);
        chart.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(xvals, yvals);
        chart.SaveImage("chart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

I'm getting following output, 
[image]

How can I remove Axis Lines both X and Y? So that my output will only the blue line.

Comment: Is `Axis.LineColor` useful to you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.linecolor(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: chartArea.AxisY.LineWidth = 0; Helped me a bit, but I able to see Lables.

Comment: chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false; Removed Lables but not markers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        chartArea.AxisY.LineWidth = 0;
        chartArea.AxisX.LineWidth = 0;
        chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        chartArea.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        chartArea.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
```

Fixed my problem

[image]